# Do reserved cards influence the end of the game?

Tags: splendor

I have some reserved cards in Splendor and 15 prestige points at the end of my turn. Is this the final round of the game, or do I have to buy all my reserved cards to end the game? Do reserved cards have some "negative" points assigned to them for points counting?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Reserved cards have no effect on the end game trigger, and do not count as negative points. The rules just say that "When a player reaches 15 prestige points, complete the current round so that each player has played the same number of turns. The player who then has the highest number of prestige points is declared the winner".

Answer (score -3):

Not officially, but it is a common house rule I have run into, among a few groups of players, that you have to have 15+ points but reserve cards count as -3 each.

So you could go out with 18 points and a reserve card, but your score is 15. Likewise if you have 15 points and a reserve card, you need to get rid of it, or get 3 more points to close it out.

Comment: Given that the rules explicitly contradict this, such a house rule would be because the players thought it fun or felt the game needed slight rebalancing and wanted to discourage players from reserving cards they didn't need.  I think that having spent your turn reserving a card that you won't use as opposed to doing something more beneficial is punishment enough and that making defensive plays by reserving something that someone else who is in the lead would have wanted adds for more exciting and interactive gameplay.  If someone suggested to me to play with this house rule I would reject it.